# Django sorl thumbnail: what should be inside {% thumbnail %} tag

Tags: django, sorl-thumbnail

My views.py:

```
# obj is of Model subclass, image is its ImageField
timg = get_thumbnail(obj.image, "160x110", quality=50)
context['timg'] = timg
return render(request, '16_upload01.html', context)
```

My template:

```
{% thumbnail timg "100x100" crop="center" as timg %}
    <img src="{{ timg.url }}" width="{{ timg.width }}" height="{{ timg.height }}">
{% empty %}
<p>No image</p>
{% endthumbnail %}
```

It shows "No image" forever. But I can see `timg` in console:

```
(Pdb) timg
<sorl.thumbnail.images.ImageFile object at 0x10f83a450>
```

Also, in settings.py I set `THUMBNAIL_DEBUG = True`, yet can't see any error show up, why?

**EDIT**

*Still NO thumbnail image shows up*

views:

```
obj = Image.objects.filter(id=1)
timg = get_thumbnail(obj.image, "160x110", quality=50)
context['timg'] = timg
return render(request, '16_upload01.html', context)
```

template:

```
<img src="{{ timg.url }}" width="{{ timg.width }}" height="{{ timg.height }}">
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to fetch the thumbnail twice; once in your view with `get_thumbnail` and then again in your template with `{% thumbnail ... %}`. Both of these do the same thing (the template tag makes use of `get_thumbnail` in the background) so pick one or the other.

[Have a look at the sorl documentation](http://sorl-thumbnail.readthedocs.org/en/latest/examples.html) and you will see the different ways of implementing thumbnails. The resulting `timg` thumbnail file - that is returned whichever approach you choose - has an `url` attribute that you can then use to display the thumbnail:

```
<img src="{{ timg.url }}" />
```

Comment: Nice enlightenment. But right now I get nothing instead of getting anything twice. I read the sorl doc for one whole day, but still get confused on even the most basic usage. For example, what's the variable after `as` in thumbnail tag?

Comment: Have you removed one of the approaches? If so which one?